# How to prevent CherryPy to log to stdout when using the logging module?

Tags: python, logging, cherrypy

I am using the `logging` module to log in my application:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

However, this causes CherryPy to log all lines two times (one in stdout, one in the logging module; which happens to be set to stdout currently):

```
[02/Jun/2023:11:17:54] ENGINE Bus STARTING
INFO:cherrypy.error:[02/Jun/2023:11:17:54] ENGINE Bus STARTING
[02/Jun/2023:11:17:54] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
INFO:cherrypy.error:[02/Jun/2023:11:17:54] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[02/Jun/2023:11:17:54] ENGINE Serving on http://0.0.0.0:5005
INFO:cherrypy.error:[02/Jun/2023:11:17:54] ENGINE Serving on http://0.0.0.0:5005
[02/Jun/2023:11:17:54] ENGINE Bus STARTED
INFO:cherrypy.error:[02/Jun/2023:11:17:54] ENGINE Bus STARTED
```

Of course, I only want the lines that are sent to the `logging` module, so I can control all logging in my application in the same way.

How can I prevent CherryPy to write the log lines also to stdout?

Answer (score 0):

In general you should avoid `basicConfig()` for all but the simplest scenarios (which is what it's intended for), because it gives you fairly limited control of the configuration.

In this case, it's simple - you can just stop the `Cherrypy` events from being passed to the root logger's handler, which you configured in the `basicConfig()` call. Here's an example which shows how to do that:

```
import logging

import cherrypy

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
# The next line prevents CherryPy events from being
# passed to the root logger's handler
logging.getLogger('cherrypy').propagate = False

class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello, world!"

logging.info('Foo')
cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

When run, this prints:

```
INFO:root:Foo
[04/Jun/2023:13:08:30] ENGINE Listening for SIGTERM.
[04/Jun/2023:13:08:30] ENGINE Listening for SIGHUP.
[04/Jun/2023:13:08:30] ENGINE Listening for SIGUSR1.
[04/Jun/2023:13:08:30] ENGINE Bus STARTING
CherryPy Checker:
The Application mounted at '' has an empty config.

[04/Jun/2023:13:08:30] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
[04/Jun/2023:13:08:30] ENGINE Serving on http://127.0.0.1:8080
[04/Jun/2023:13:08:30] ENGINE Bus STARTED
```

Comment: Isn't this the exact opposite of what I asked? Still nice to not see double lines, but I want them in the logger, so when I change the logger to log to a file or something else, I do get the cherrypy log lines.

Comment: There is no "the logger", as Cherrypy has its own logger(s) and your application has its logger or loggers. Perhaps I misunderstood "all logging in my application" to mean logging to _your_ loggers, as opposed to CherryPy's loggers. Do you mean handler? Handlers are what output to destinations like console and file.